# Anyons under weaker assumptions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, topological-field-theory, anyons, category-theory

**I. Duality assumption**

In [Anyons in an exactly solved model and beyond](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438) p.74,  Kitaev says, "*We will see that for theories with particle-antiparticle duality*, condition 3 can be dispensed with."

Of course, the duality axiom (i.e. an anyonic charges has an anti-charge) is well motivated from microscopic models of topological orders (e.g. spin lattices), and it seems (intuitively) reasonable to demand that any system of excitations should be initialisable from the vacuum state.

In the literature, duality is taken as a given for the theory of anyons - but the quoted sentence above raises the question,

> 1. Are there any studies of anyon theories *without* particle-antiparticle duality?

I'm guessing there isn't currently much physical motivation for exploration in this direction? Mathematically, I'm not sure if there are any results regarding classification of the corresponding structures (I suppose these would be non-rigid predecessors of unitary braided fusion categories).

**II. Finiteness assumptions**

For a theory of anyons, it is assumed that,

- The number of different types of anyons is finite
- Fusion coefficients are finite

> 2. Why the finiteness assumptions? (Apart from avoiding unwieldy structures).

*A (very dodgy) sketch attempt at an explanation for finiteness of distinct anyon types in a theory:*

**A.** Since the Hamiltonian of a topological phase is *gapped*, there exists some $\Delta>0$ such that the difference between any two distinct eigenenergies is greater than $\Delta$.

**B.** Any nontrivial anyon has an associated energy corresponding to a (non-ground state) eigenenergy. The trivial anyon (vacuum) corresponds to the ground state energy.

**C.** By A & B, an infinite number of different types of anyons means the topological phase can realise anyons with infinite energies (and these energies are localised). This is bad...

> I'm *extremely* uncertain about point B of that sketch though, and I'm not all too confident about point A either. Point C is just running away from infinities. *Comments regarding point B would be very welcome!*
>
> I don't have any idea about the finite fusion coefficients though - I know this amounts to demanding that the superselection sectors have finite dimension, but why is this reasonable?